# Cannot change variable using click event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to change global variable `finish` from `false` to `true` using click event in order to prevent hovering the circles.
After I use click event, my global variable `finish` did not change (it is still `false`) and I can still do hovering over some circles.
Why is that happening?

```js
var finish = false;

$( ".rating-circle" ).click( function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "rating-chosen" );
    $( this ).prevAll().addClass( "rating-chosen" );
    finish = true;
});

if ( finish == false )
{
    $( ".rating-circle" ).hover( 
     function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "rating-hover" );
      $( this ).prevAll().addClass( "rating-hover" );
    }, 
      function() {
      $( this ).removeClass( "rating-hover" )
      $( this ).prevAll().removeClass( "rating-hover" );
    } );
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}
.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Finding elements using jQuery</h2>
<h3>Rate this session</h3>
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your checking logic takes place above your hover event binding, so it is only evaluated *once* when the code is first run. You need to check the `finish` flag within the handler function itself, or you could just unbind the handlers on click.

```
$( ".rating-circle" ).hover(function() {
  if (finish) return;

  $( this ).addClass( "rating-hover" );
  $( this ).prevAll().addClass( "rating-hover" );
}, function() {
  $( this ).removeClass( "rating-hover" )
  $( this ).prevAll().removeClass( "rating-hover" );
} );
```

Also, it would be more idiomatic/semantic to name your flag something like `finished` or `hasFinished`.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable does change, but it's too little too late, by that time the event handlers are already bound, and the condition doesn't matter.

As you're adding a unique class anyway on click, you could just check for that class inside the `hover` events

```js
$(".rating-circle").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("rating-chosen");
  $(this).prevAll().addClass("rating-chosen");
});

$(".rating-circle").hover(
  function() {
    if ($(".rating-circle.rating-chosen").length === 0) {
      $(this).addClass("rating-hover");
      $(this).prevAll().addClass("rating-hover");
    }
  },
  function() {
    if ($(".rating-circle.rating-chosen").length === 0) {
      $(this).removeClass("rating-hover")
      $(this).prevAll().removeClass("rating-hover");
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}

.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Finding elements using jQuery</h2>
<h3>Rate this session</h3>
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var finish = false;

$( ".rating-circle" ).click( function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "rating-chosen" );
    $( this ).prevAll().addClass( "rating-chosen" );
    finish = true;
});

$( ".rating-circle" ).hover( function() {
  if ( finish == false ){
    $( this ).addClass( "rating-hover" );
    $( this ).prevAll().addClass( "rating-hover" );
  }
},function(){
  if ( finish == false ){
    $( this ).removeClass( "rating-hover" )
    $( this ).prevAll().removeClass( "rating-hover" );
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
  color: darkblue;
}
.rating-circle {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-radius: 1.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1em;
}

.rating-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rating-chosen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Finding elements using jQuery</h2>
<h3>Rate this session</h3>
<div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```